# Self service portal/ PaaS using Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am just curious of accomplishing the following unrelated things.

1. Learn Yesod/Haskell
2. Create a self service portal within my company, where people can come and create their own linux containers (LXC), get access to them and be able to destroy them once they finish using. Planning to give each users a quota of having 10 containers and have some restrictions.

I have some experience in doing [2] using Rails.

Now, can I implement such a thing in Yesod? Will my [1] be accomplished by doing [2]? Can I do that in fact? What pros and cons do I have in creating such an app in Yesod?

Answer (score 2):

> Now, can I implement such a thing in Yesod?

Yes.

> Will my [1] be accomplished by doing [2]?

To a certain extent. You will learn the concepts that you will use to implement [2].

> Can I do that in fact?

Yes.

> What pros and cons do I have in creating such an app in Yesod

You will learn to design applications in Haskell in general and web applications in Yesod specifically.

The steep learning curve (depeding on your experience with haskell) can be called a cons but it is time worth spending.

Comment: As someone who is still in the foothills of the Haskell learning-curve I would recommend getting the LXC stuff working as a simple command-line app first. Haskell type-errors are confusing to a newbie and any framework type-errors I found to be basically useless at describing what I did wrong.